# Bower dependencies for acceptance testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit, ember-testing

I'm trying to get started with acceptance testing in ember-app-kit. When I run grunt test though I get AuthenticatedRouteMixin undefined (from ember-simple-auth). This isn't a problem when I run the app with grunt server so I presume my bower dependencies aren't being loaded for the acceptance tests. Is there something I need to setup to get the bower dependencies loaded for the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ember-app-kit uses karma you need to configure all dependencies in your karma.conf.js. There's an array called files, just include any dependencies in here.